# How to fix type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast error

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to make an async API call and I keep getting this error which I assume is for the body_y but I don't understand what its saying or how to fix it exactly. Any help is appreciated

```
Future<void> _makePostRequest() async {
// set up POST request arguments
String url = 'https://myUrl';
//print(accessToken);
Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+accessToken};

Map<String, String> body_y = {
    "contactName": {
"firstName": "abc",
"middleName": "def",
"lastName": "ff",
"type": "RETAIL",
"companyName": "Company",
"tradeName": "Merchant"
}
,
"notificationPreferences": [
{
"notificationHandleType": "EMAIL",
"notificationHandle": "b@beta.yahoo.ac"
}
],
"notificationLanguage": "EN" };
  
 

   // make POST request
    Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: body_y);
    // check the status code for the result
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    print(statusCode);
    // this API passes back the id of the new item added to the body
    String body = response.body;
  
  }
```

Comment: could you add the code for your post function or is that part of the `http` package?

Comment: yup, its part of the http package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` takes a `String` but a `Map<String, String` is passed. Try encoding to `json`.

```
import 'dart:convert`;

// Change from Map<String,String> to Map<String,dynamic>
Map<String, dynamic> body_y = {
  "contactName": {
    "firstName": "abc",
    "middleName": "def",
    "lastName": "ff",
    "type": "RETAIL",
    "companyName": "Company",
    "tradeName": "Merchant"
  },
  "notificationPreferences": [
    {
       "notificationHandleType": "EMAIL",
       "notificationHandle": "b@beta.yahoo.ac"
    } 
  ],
  "notificationLanguage": "EN",
};

Response response = await post(
  url, 
  headers: headers, 
  body: json.encode(body_y), // encode to json
);

var body = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>; // decode json to map

String id = body['id']; // if it's named 'id'
```

Comment: I tried this, but the data in the initial declaration of  Map<String, String> = data is red underlined with the error: the element type MAP<String, string> cant be assigned to the map value type String

Comment: Yeah it's not Map<String, String>, U have a <String, List> and <String, Map> as well. Try converting it to Map<String, dynamic> body_y;